# How to call this Swift function from Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, function

I know this question was asked and answered but none of the answers seem relevant here. They all seem to assume the Swift function is in a Swift class, but I don't have a Swift class.

I made a minimal Objc app to illustrate my problem with code in only ViewController.m and a file I added named "abcFunction.swift". When I added the Swift file a -Bridging-Header.h file was made automatically.

ViewController.m contains only 8 lines:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSString *s = abc(@"xxx");
   NSLog(@"returned string is %@", s);
}
@end
```

and abcFunction.swift contains only 5 lines:

```
import UIKit
func abc(_ arg: NSString) -> NSString {
   let s = "arg is \(arg)"
   return s as NSString
}
```

The line in ViewController.m that calls the abc function gets 2 errors and 2 warnings. They seem to indicate that Objective-C doesn't recognize that abc(@"xxx") is referencing a Swift function. The errors are "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString' is disallowed with ARC", and "Implicit declaration of function 'abc' is invalid in C99"

Note that the swift function is NOT a member of a class -- it's just a bare function. Isn't it possible to reference such a function from Objective-C? How should I do it?

I've tried many variations including importing things that I could think of, but nothing helped. Quoting all that I tried would make this question too long.

How can I make this example app compile and run? I've gotten very rusty on Objective-C so I'm probably missing something totally obvious.

Comment: Where in your Objective-C files are you including the bridging header?

Comment: “a -Bridging-Header.h file was made automatically” That is irrelevant.

Comment: In ViewController.h file define this method `-(NSString *)abc:(NSString *)a;` and in ViewController.m File `#import "PROJECT NAME-Swift.h"` also in ViewDidLoad define this way --> `ABCFunction *myClass = [ABCFunction new];
    NSString *s = [myClass abc:@"Hello"];
    NSLog(@"%@", s);`

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate, and I already explained why in the question... the existing replies are based on the abc function being in a swift class. My question, as stated, is about a swift function that is NOT in a class. I got past the problem by putting it in a class (i.e, it is now tagged with "@objc static") and adjusting the calling methods accordingly. But the question wasn't answered. I would still like to know if a bare swift function is accessible from objc.